# ScrollView with LinearLayout child does not wrap_content correctly

Tags: android, layout

So, I have the following .xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.scopesystems.cityalert.ui.Despre"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_despre"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_incercare">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linear_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.8" >
            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--General-->
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/sectionHeader"
        android:text="@string/general"
        />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/despre_general"/>
        <!--Evaluti-ne-->
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/sectionHeader"
        android:text="@string/evaluatine"
        />
        <!--Confidentialitate si licente-->
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/sectionHeader"
        android:text="@string/confidentialitate"
        />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/despre_politici"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The issue is that the last `ListView` is on only 1 row, and it has to be scrolled to display all the items in the list. I tried to add to the `linear_parent` a height of `match_parent` but it wont let me, it says that I should use instead `wrapcontent`. How can i change the layout to display the items on all the screen, not just half?[image]

Comment: Add this code in scrollView; android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: `wrap_content` `ListView`s are a bad idea, that's likely your problem

Comment: @MuratÇakır I have tried with `android:fillViewport="true" ` and indeed it's working now!

Comment: Okay, if it worked, i added as an answer to this issue solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, On the ScrollView use `android:fillViewport="true"` and for child of ScrollView `android:height="wrap_content"`.